# longtable inside adjustbox

Tags: longtable, scaling, width

The following `longtable` (or `longtabu`) is too wide. Naive as I am, I have put the table into a `adjustbox`, but it does not compile.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{longtable}{*{6}{c}}
    &
    Homer J. Simpson &
    Marge Simpson &
    Bart Simpson &
    Lisa Simpson &
    Maggie Simpson 
\\
\hline
\endhead
    Age &
    38 &
    34 &
    10 &
    8  &
    1
\\
\end{longtable}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to auto-adjust the table width to `\textwidth`?

**Update:**

I get the expected result, if I replace `longtable` by `tabular` and remove `\endhead`. But I need a table that can be split across pages. And I don't want line breaking inside the cells - I would like to scale the width of the entire table.

Comment: A box cannot be split across pages.

Comment: When the table is only too wide but not too long, you could use a `table` instead of a `longtable`, e.g. something like `\begin{table}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}[tbph]{cccccc}
    &
    Homer J. Simpson &
    Marge Simpson &
    Bart Simpson &
    Lisa Simpson &
    Maggie Simpson 
\\
\hline
    Age &
    38 &
    34 &
    10 &
    8  &
    1
\\
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}`.

Comment: @Stephen Sorry, I didn't mentioned that, but the table also too long.

Comment: Can't the column heads be multilined?

Comment: @Bernard Please see the update.

Comment: @sergej: Then @AboAmmar's answer, with the `ltablex` package, is the solution. You even can go down to `\footnotesize` for the font if necessarywhile keeping legibility.. Or you can use the `landscape` package, but the table will then be on its own pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ltablex,array}
\usepackage[textheight=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{6}{L}}
    & Homer J. Simpson & Marge Simpson & Bart Simpson & Lisa Simpson & Maggie Simpson \\
\hline \endhead
    Age &   38 &   34 &   10 &   8  &   1 \\
    Age &   38 &   34 &   10 &   8  &   1 \\
    Age &   38 &   34 &   10 &   8  &   1 \\
    Age &   38 &   34 &   10 &   8  &   1 \\
    Age &   38 &   34 &   10 &   8  &   1 \\
    Age &   38 &   34 &   10 &   8  &   1 \\
    Age &   38 &   34 &   10 &   8  &   1 \\
    Age &   38 &   34 &   10 &   8  &   1 \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

You need two functionalities; 1) the table should be `\textwidth`, 2) the table should run across pages, then, you need both `tabularx` and `longtable` together. The solution is to use the `ltablex` package, which provides `tabularx` with the ability to break at page borders exactly as `longtable` does. I have defined a `newcolumntype` left justified `{L}`, but you can neglect it if you choose to. Also, I have set a very short page height just for the example. In your document, you needn't do this.

If the table is still too wide, you can set a `\small` font size or shrink inter-column spaces (by, e.g., `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}`). Too many questions also can be found on the site for this specific point.

**Update**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ltablex,array}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\footnotesize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{C*{5}{c}}
    & Homer J. Simpson & Marge Simpson & Bart Simpson & Lisa Simpson & Maggie Simpson \\
\hline \endhead
    Age &   38 &   34 &   10 &   8  &   1 \\
    Age &   38 &   34 &   10 &   8  &   1 \\
    Age &   38 &   34 &   10 &   8  &   1 \\
    Age &   38 &   34 &   10 &   8  &   1 \\
    Age &   38 &   34 &   10 &   8  &   1 \\
    Age &   38 &   34 &   10 &   8  &   1 \\
    Age &   38 &   34 &   10 &   8  &   1 \\
    Age &   38 &   34 &   10 &   8  &   1 \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem to work if I remove the `geometry` package and use column type `c`.

Comment: @sergej  `geometry` has nothing to do with the table, it is merely used to shorten a page to show you how the page break can be. In addition, if you want to center the cells, just change the `L` column definition to `\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}`, for example, and use `{*{6}{C}}` as column specifiers.

Comment: If I remove the `geometry` package, then the column heads are multilined. See [here](https://www.overleaf.com/3111625xngrnk#/8661638/)

Comment: @sergej  Please see my update.